# Installing Java but being blocked by Permission Denied

Tags: java

I am trying to install java on my raspberry pi following the instructions on: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html, but at the instruction `./bin/java -version`, I get Permission denied. I tried doing `sudo ./bin/java -version`, but I get command not found. I am logged in on the root, so I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: I think the problem when using sudo is that the java environment variable is not set for the root user.

Comment: So you are really using Debian and not Raspbian? Instead of using Java with Raspbian with more Performance. Java from Oracle for Raspbian is only available at the moment as java 8 "beta" release.

Comment: @SteveRobillard For some reason, typing in `./bin/java`, even though it goes to an elf file, it doesn't execute it which is the problem

Comment: @otakun85 Sorry for the confusion, I'm running raspian (from the raspberry pi website) and I'm trying to run a Java application on it. Preferably something that would run java files the same on a desktop (or as similar) that it does on another device with java

Answer (score 3):

Java 8 is available as an early release for the Raspberry Pi.  This includes JDK8 and JavaFX 8 early release.

Checkout http://jdk8.java.net/fxarmpreview/

```
johnma@raspbmc:~$ /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-b36e)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b04, mixed mode)
johnma@raspbmc:~$
```

Also, I suspect that you received program not found because the version of the executable was not compatible with the platform that you tried to run the executable on.  I accidentally downloaded a JDK7 preview for ARM instead of the most current JDK8 preview and received the same "command not found" error that you did.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found a way around it. It's probably very silly, but it seems to work.

I run `apt-get install openjdk-6-jre`, which bundles java and now I am able to call `java -jar TCA.jar` and it does the same io reading and writing as done on my desktop version (which helps with my debugging), but I am still testing the other objects in it. So far, I haven't found any issues.

Comment: Damn it, didn't really work. Most of the libraries I want to use (like a lot of the System) doesn't work. Think I need one tailored for raspberry pi